# Dijkstra's Algorithm Java: Last edge always gets added instead of shortest

Tags: java, algorithm, dijkstra

I have a vertex I am trying to reach, called destination. Currently my algorithm seems to run past this vertex.

It appears that the last edge to get tested for the shortest distance is always added. I'm not sure if this is due to an error in my algorithm or how I add Neighbors, but I have been trying to test both.

Sometimes the last 2 edges get added, ex:

> ID: 39330 Value: 1.309999942779541
>
> ID: 39360 Value: 1.940000057220459
>
> ID: 39374 Value: 1.9700000286102295
>
> Added: 39360 Added: 39374

Or just the last one is added:

> ID: 39347 Value: 1.2999999523162842
>
> ID: 24955 Value: 2.5799999237060547
>
> Added: 24955

Any thoughts, recommendations or ideas are greatly appreciated!

***Graph***

```
class Graph {
    private final Set<Vertex> vertices = new HashSet<Vertex>();
    private final Set<Edge> edges = new HashSet<Edge>();

    public void addVertex(int id, String name) {
        Vertex vertex = new Vertex(id,name);
        vertices.add(vertex);
        //System.out.println("ID:" +  vertex.getID() + "Name:" + vertex.getName());
    }
    public void addEdge(double weight, Vertex vertex1, Vertex vertex2, String extra) {
        Edge edge = new Edge(weight,vertex1,vertex2,extra);
        edges.add(edge);        
    }
    public void printVertices() {
        for(Vertex vertex : vertices){
               System.out.println("ID:" + vertex.getID() + " Name:" + vertex.getName());
            }   
    }
    public void printEdges() {
        for(Edge edge : edges){
               System.out.println("StartVertex:" + edge.getStartVertex() + "ID: "+ edge.getStartVertex().getID() +" EndVertex:" + edge.getTargetVertex()+"ID: "+ edge.getTargetVertex().getID() + "Weight:" + edge.getWeight());
            }

    }
    public Vertex getVertex(Vertex v) {
        return v;
    }
    public Map<Vertex, Double> getNeighbours(Vertex vertex) {
         Map<Vertex,Double> neighbors = new HashMap();

         Object[] check = edges.toArray();
         Object[] check2 = vertices.toArray();

         for(int i = 0; i < edges.size(); i++) {

            if(((Edge) check[i]).getStartVertex().getID() == vertex.getID()) {
                neighbors.put(((Edge) check[i]).getTargetVertex(),((Edge) check[i]).getWeight());
            }
            //check for 
            /*else if(((Edge) check[i]).getTargetVertex() == vertex) {
                neighbors.put(((Edge) check[i]).getStartVertex(),((Edge) check[i]).getWeight());
            }*/
         }
         for (Entry<Vertex, Double> entry : neighbors.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println("ID: " + entry.getKey().getID() +  " Value: " + entry.getValue() );
            }
        return neighbors; 
     }
}
```

***ShortestPathFinder***

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Set;

class ShortestPathFinder {
        private  Graph graph = new Graph();
        private  Vertex source = new Vertex(0, null);
        private Vertex destination = new Vertex(0,null);
        private  Map<Vertex,Double> minimumWeightToVertices = new HashMap();
        private  Map<Vertex,Vertex> previousVertex = new HashMap();
        private  Set<Vertex> visited =  new HashSet();

        private  Map<Vertex,Double> neighbors = new HashMap();

    public Optional<Path> findShortestPath(Graph graph, Vertex source, Vertex destination) {
        this.graph = graph;
        this.source = graph.getVertex(source);
        this.destination = graph.getVertex(destination);
        Optional<Path> pathFound = Optional.empty();

        //start queue at source vertex
        source.setDistance(0);
        PriorityQueue<Vertex> priorityQueue = new PriorityQueue<>();
        priorityQueue.add(source);
        source.setVisited(true);

        while( !priorityQueue.isEmpty() ){
          // Getting the minimum distance vertex from priority queue
          Vertex actualVertex = priorityQueue.poll();   
          //get Neighbors of source vertex 
          neighbors = graph.getNeighbours(actualVertex);
        //find Neighbor with lowest weight
          for(Entry<Vertex, Double> neighbor : neighbors.entrySet()){             
                 Vertex v = neighbor.getKey();
                if(v.getID() == destination.getID()) {
                    minimumWeightToVertices.put(v,v.getDistance());
                    v.setPredecessor(actualVertex);
                    previousVertex.put(actualVertex,v);
                    priorityQueue.add(v);
                    // found, set pathFound = Optional.of(path) 
                    Path path = new Path();
                    pathFound = Optional.of(path);
                }
                else if(visited.contains(v) == false)
                {
                    double newDistance = actualVertex.getDistance() + neighbor.getValue();

                    //when found min add to minmumWeightToVertices
                    if( newDistance < v.getDistance() ){
                        priorityQueue.remove(v);
                        v.setDistance(newDistance);
                        minimumWeightToVertices.put(v,newDistance);
                        v.setPredecessor(actualVertex);
                        previousVertex.put(actualVertex,v);
                        priorityQueue.add(v);
                        System.out.println("Added: " + v.getID());
                    }
                }
            }
           //When visited add to visited so not visited again
            actualVertex.setVisited(true);
            visited.add(actualVertex);  
          //continue getting neighbors with lowest index until destination reached 
        }       
        return pathFound;       
    }

    public void getPath() {     
        //print all info using previous Vertex and print out edge info from it
        for (Entry<Vertex, Vertex> entry : previousVertex.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("ID: " + entry.getKey().getID() + " Name: " + entry.getKey().getName() +
                    " to  "  + "ID: " + entry.getValue().getID() + " Name: " + entry.getValue().getName());
        }
    }
}
```

***Edge***

```
public class Edge {

    private double weight;
    private Vertex startVertex;
    private Vertex targetVertex;
    private String extra;

    public Edge(double weight, Vertex startVertex, Vertex targetVertex, String extra) {
        this.weight = weight;
        this.startVertex = startVertex;
        this.targetVertex = targetVertex;
        this.extra = extra;
    }

    public double getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(double weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public Vertex getStartVertex() {
        return startVertex;
    }

    public void setStartVertex (Vertex startVertex) {
        this.startVertex = startVertex;
    }

    public Vertex getTargetVertex() {
        return targetVertex;
    }

    public void setTargetVertex(Vertex targetVertex) {
        this.targetVertex = targetVertex;
    }
    public String getExtra() {
        return extra;
    }
    public void setExtra(String extra) {
        this.extra = extra;
    }
}
```

***Vertex***

```
public class Vertex implements Comparable<Vertex> {

    private int ID;
    private String name;
    private List<Edge> adjacenciesList;
    private boolean visited;
    private Vertex predecessor;
    private double distance = Double.MAX_VALUE;

    public Vertex(int ID, String name) { //(Int ID, String name)?
        this.ID = ID;
        this.name = name;
        this.adjacenciesList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addNeighbour(Edge edge) {
        this.adjacenciesList.add(edge);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Edge> getAdjacenciesList() {
        return adjacenciesList;
    }

    public void setAdjacenciesList(List<Edge> adjacenciesList) {
        this.adjacenciesList = adjacenciesList;
    }

    public boolean isVisited() {
        return visited;
    }

    public void setVisited(boolean visited) {
        this.visited = visited;
    }

    public Vertex getPredecessor() {
        return predecessor;
    }

    public void setPredecessor(Vertex predecessor) {
        this.predecessor = predecessor;
    }

    public double getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public void setDistance(double distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Vertex otherVertex) {
        return Double.compare(this.distance, otherVertex.getDistance());
    }
}
```

***ReadInput***

```
public class ReadInput {
    Vertex[] vertex = new Vertex[25252];
    final String DELIMITER = ",";
    int indexVertex = 0;

    //public Vertex[] readVertices() throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
    public Graph readFromStream() throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
         Graph graph = new Graph();
         //25252 number of elements in Place.txt file   

        //Delimiter used in CSV file
            String line = "";
            //Create the file reader
            BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Place.txt"));
            String IDString = null;
            String name = null;
            int ID = 0;
            //Read the file line by line
            while ((line = fileReader.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                //Get all tokens available in line
                String[] tokens = line.split(DELIMITER);
                //for(String token : tokens)
                //{
                     IDString = tokens[0];
                     name = tokens[1];
                     ID = Integer.parseInt(IDString);
                //}
                 vertex[indexVertex] = new Vertex(ID,name);

                 graph.addVertex(ID,name);
                //System.out.println(indexVertex +":" + vertex[indexVertex].getID());
                indexVertex++;
            }
            fileReader.close();
            //return vertex;        
    //}
    //public Edge[] readEdges() throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
        Edge[] edge = new Edge[127807];
        int indexEdge = 0; 
        String line2 = "";
        BufferedReader fileReader2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Road.txt"));
        String valueString = null;
        String vertex1IDName = null;
        String vertex2IDName = null;
        String extra = null;
        float value = 0;
        int vertex1ID = 0;
        int vertex2ID = 0;
        //Read the file line by line
        while ((line2 = fileReader2.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            //Get all tokens available in line
            String[] tokens2 = line2.split(DELIMITER);
            //for(String token1 : tokens2)
            //{
                vertex1IDName = tokens2[0];
                vertex2IDName = tokens2[1];
                valueString = tokens2[2];
                if(tokens2.length - 1 == 3) {
                    extra = tokens2[tokens2.length - 1];
                }
                else {
                    extra = "";
                }
                vertex1ID = Integer.parseInt(vertex1IDName);
                vertex2ID = Integer.parseInt(vertex2IDName);
                value = Float.parseFloat(valueString);

                //adds all edges with null vertex names, need to account for edges that connect to actual vertices?
                Vertex vertex1 = new Vertex(vertex1ID,"null");
                Vertex vertex2 = new Vertex(vertex2ID,"null");

                graph.addEdge(value,vertex1, vertex2, extra);  
        }
        fileReader2.close();
        return graph;
        //return edge;
    }
    public Vertex calcualteDestination() {

        Scanner scanUserInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the Destination Name:");
        String destinationName = scanUserInput.nextLine();
        scanUserInput.close();

         Vertex Destination = new Vertex(0,null);

       for(int i = 0; i<indexVertex; i++) {
           if(destinationName.equals(vertex[i].getName())){
               Destination.setID(vertex[i].getID());
               Destination.setName(vertex[i].getName());    
           }
       } 
        return Destination;
    }

    public Vertex calculatesSource() {
        Scanner scanUserInput = new Scanner(System.in);  
        System.out.println("Enter the Source Name:");
        String sourceName = scanUserInput.nextLine();

        Vertex Source = new Vertex(0, null);

        for(int i = 0; i<indexVertex; i++) {
            if(sourceName.equals(vertex[i].getName())){
                Source.setID(vertex[i].getID());
                Source.setName(vertex[i].getName());    
            }
        }   

        return Source;
    }   
}
```

***Main***

```
ppublic class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {

        ReadInput graphReader = new ReadInput();
        Graph graph = graphReader.readFromStream();
        Vertex source = graphReader.calculatesSource();
        Vertex destination = graphReader.calcualteDestination();

        //graph.printEdges();    
        //graph.printVertices();

        ShortestPathFinder finder = new ShortestPathFinder();
        Optional<Path> possiblePath = finder.findShortestPath(graph,source,destination);
        if(possiblePath.isPresent() == false) {
            System.out.println("No path found");
        }
        else {
             System.out.println("Shortest path:");
             finder.getPath();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you `return pathFound;` immediately when you find it?

Answer (score 1):

You should immediately return `pathFound` when you find a path.

```
if (v.getID() == destination.getID()) {
    ...
    return Optional.of(path);
}
```

Otherwise, you are not only wasting time exploring the rest of the graph, but you may even find a different, *longer* path to the target and overwrite the shortest path with that one.

It's also a bit odd that at this point, `path` is just `new Path()`. It seems like you only use this to mark the `Optional` as non-empty while leaving the actual information about the path in the `ShortestPathFinder`'s `previousVertex` map. Better put the path information directly into the `Path` object, unrolling it in a similar way as you do in `getPath`.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation, but returning immediately didn't seem to change anything.  If 3 possible edges are looked it, it always adds the last one ie:                  ID: 67559 Value: 2.7100000381469727
ID: 67861 Value: 7.420000076293945
ID: 86357 Value: 2.759999990463257
Added: 86357                                                                                                                        I'm not sure if this is an error with how I get neighbors or the comparison itself, but this may be why I dont reach the destination